# How can I pass a callback function into an $.ajax.done callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, promise

I'm calling a function, which makes an `ajax GET` to a url, like this:

```
// parameters = url, callback, boolean
that.mapUrl( window.location.search, function(spec) {
    console.log("initial mapping done");
    console.log(spec);
    // do stuff
  }, true);
```

`mapUrl` will trigger an Ajax request. Inside the Ajax `done` or `success` handler, I want to trigger my callback function, but doing it like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: obj[1],
    context: $('body')
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("FAILED");
    configuration = {
      "errorThrown":errorThrown,
      "textStatus": textStatus,
      "jqXHR": jqXHR
    }    
  }).done(function(value, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("OK");
    console.log(callback) // undefined!
    configuration = {
      "value":value,
      "textStatus": textStatus,
      "jqXHR": jqXHR
    }
  });
```

**Question**:
So I'm wondering how to pass my callback function into the `ajax` `done-callback`. Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Here is the full `mapURL` function

```
that.mapUrl = function (spec, callback, internal) {
  var key,
    obj,
    parsedJSON,
    configuration = {"root" : window.location.href};

  if (spec !== undefined && spec !== "") {
    obj = spec.slice(1).split("=");
    key = obj[0];
    console.log(key);
    switch (key) {
    case "file":
      $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: obj[1],
        context: $('body')
      }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("FAILED");
        configuration = {
          "errorThrown":errorThrown,
          "textStatus": textStatus,
          "jqXHR": jqXHR
        }
      }).done(function(value, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("OK");
        configuration = {
          "value":value,
          "textStatus": textStatus,
          "jqXHR": jqXHR
        }
      });
      break;
    default:
      // type not allowed, ignore
      configuration.src = [];
      break;
    }
  }
  return configuration;
};
```

Comment: Can you share the method declaration `mapUrl

Comment: one second, coming up

Comment: You call the method? Not sure what is the problem. Show what you tried.

Comment: Is there an actual method your passing in for the `callback`?

Comment: yes, I'm calling `myplugin.mapUrl(window.location.href, function (d) {}, false);` I also get the **OK** console, but I cannot access the callback.

Comment: @frequent: Can you access it from outside the success callback? Please try a `console.log` in the top of your function. Probably you've got a typo somewhere

Comment: @Bergi: yes console.logging outside returns my function.

Comment: there's definitely something odd going on - there's no reason that `callback` shouldn't be in scope everywhere within `that.mapUrl`.  The promise approach will be better in the long run, anyway.

Comment: also - I noticed that you're trying to set `configuration` in the AJAX `done` callback function, and then return it.  That won't work.  This is another good reason to use the promise interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be generally better to preserve the "promise" interface rather than passing callbacks into your code.  This will allow you to better trap error conditions.

```
function mapUrl(url) {
    return $.ajax(...)
            .fail(...)
            .then(function(data) {
                // preprocess data and return it
            });
}
```

where using `.then` you can manipulate the returned data before it's passed to the callback:

```
mapUrl(...).done(function(data) {
    // data has been preprocessed
    ...
});
```

If the AJAX call fails, you can chain additional `.fail` handlers at this point too, which your current API would not permit.  This "separation of concerns" would let you put nicer error handling UI in place, for example, without cluttering your AJAX code with UI-related code.

Comment: @frequent glad to have helped! :)